# Silex getBaseUrl and getBasePath empty

Tags: php, silex

I'm sort of new to Silex and learning.  I'm trying to return the base url inside one of my route controllers to return the new path after inserting a row into a database.  No matter what I try it's returning an empty string though.  Here's part of that function:

```
$app->match('/item', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

    $method = $request->getMethod();

    switch ($method) {
        //POST  
        case 'POST': //insert
            $data = array(
                'item' => $request->get('item'),
                'description'  => $request->get('description'),
                'quantityOnHand' => $request->get('quantityOnHand'),
                'reorderPoint' => $request->get('reorderPoint'),
                'supplier_id' => $request->get('supplier_id')
                ); //before to get supplier_id???? Or do it in ios

            $app['db']->insert('inventory', $data);
            $newId = (int) $app['db']->lastInsertId(); //cast int 
            $location = $request->getBaseUrl().'/inventory/id/'.$newId;

            return $app->json(array('status' => 201, 'id'=>$newId, 'location' =>$location), 201);

            break;
     }
}
```

Everything in the `$location` variable is working except the base path.  Am I missing something? I'm injecting the `$request` into the controller.  When I run this it returns `/inventory/item/101` for the location, without my base url.

Comment: And which is your base URL? Which URL do you type in your browser? Also can you share your project layout (on filesystem) and your .htaccess?

Comment: Everything is just in the index file right now (small project).  I assumed that Silex came with it's own method for returning the base url.  HTACCESS only containes `Options -Indexes`

Comment: Yes it should. But the configuration that I am asking for affects the base url that's why I did ask... You haven't told which base url are you expecting, maybe you should read the explanation of [```getBaseUrl```](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L928) and [```getBasePath```](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L907) methods?

Comment: It was my understanding from reading that the `getBaseUrl` will return the web address root.  And my apologies I sent the wrong htaccess.  This is the htaccess for it: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: It seems your base url is indeed ```/```. Your defined route is */item* and your rewrite rule does not contain any directory, so which base url are you expecting?

Comment: I was hoping to just grab my base url.  www.url.com so I didn't manually type it when I needed it as I think this is bad practice.  If the hosting ever changed or I wanted to move it.

Comment: ```www.url.com``` is not your base url. ```/``` is when the url is ```www.url.com```. ```www.url.com``` is your domain name or hostname. [Check out the ```getHost``` method](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getHost), which has what you are looking for.

Comment: PS: It may be easier to use a [UrlGenerator](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/url_generator.html)

Comment: getHost did it. I was barking up the wrong tree lol.  If you add answer I'll accept.  Thank you!!

Comment: There you have, we can close this one now. Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems that what the OP is looking for is the hostname, not the base url, so the [`getHost`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getHost) method should be used.

Remember, though, that to generate URLs easily you should use the [UrlGenerator](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/routing/introduction.html#generate-a-url) instead of crafting it manually. [Silex has a default provider for this service](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/url_generator.html).